# Type-C headphone not working on Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: audio-jack

I am using a Type-C to 3.5mm jack converter for my android device, I use the same setup for my laptop running Ubuntu 22.04 but it doesn't work, Why?

Comment: Why do you expect that this converter should work for a pc?

Comment: sorry for my mistake, I thought type C for everything>